# How to make a regression model efficient?

Tags: image, regression, linear-regression, non-linear-regression

I am using the first three column as three different independent variables and trying to find the value of dependent variable which is in the fourth column. Here is a piece of data and results. With these details, I am trying to formulate an equation. So I used Multiple Regression model and got the following predicted value which is in the fifth column. Although for some data, the model is right, It is not right for most of the results. How can I use the data I have to create a model or equation in generic form? Is there anyways to improve this? I used confidentiality limit of 95%

```
    255 216 0       0.106       0.264531693
    255 255 255     0.144       0.146814881
    1   255 255     0.158       0.278869742
    168 168 168     0.186       0.341845818
    0   255 1       0.229       0.33885068
    254 106 0       0.26        0.428702478
    0   148 254     0.324       0.438811419
```

Comment: I would start by checking scatterplots of each independent variable vs. the dependent variable to look for any apparent trend. It is possible you might find something useful, such as a clearly visible log transform might be used. You might see something like i.e. col5 = (a * col1) + (b * log(col2)) + (c * col3^2) + (d * col4) + offset. Maybe just adding an offset parameter alone to the current fit would help, that's easy and quick to test.

Comment: Thanks @JamesPhillips